# What are these very heavy blocks found on my family's property?

Tags: construction, metal, materials

I need help identifying these blocks found on my family's property, which was a 17th century farm house in Virginia. The blocks are 8.75" long, 4.5" wide, and 5" high and weigh 58 lbs.

[image: image of stone block]

Comment: Those measurements are the dimensions of cobblestone.

Comment: ...and looks like granite, not that "granite" is all that specific.

Comment: Why did you choose the tag for "metal?"

Comment: I was thinking granite blocks also I guess we should say brown granite since the color varies.

Comment: What would you like to know about them?

Comment: I don't think granite would weigh that much. It weighs about 170 lbs. per cubic foot. Here we have about .12 cubic feet, which would weigh about 20 lbs. A cubic foot would weigh over 500 lbs. This probably has a lot more iron or other metal in it That said, this isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: Ha!  Good point @isherwood OP's measured density is closer to a medium density metal than to any known rock.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density#Various_materials

Comment: Debatable whether understanding historical home improvements is in scope here.   I think it should be.  Regardless you'd do well to post this in FB groups like Historic Home Renovations, Our Old House, Victorian Home Restoration and Appreciation, and several other such groups.  Those communities are more amenable to chat and exploration.

Comment: Could also hit up a local high school or college science teacher.

Comment: My guess is it was used as a counterweight

Comment: I was trying to figure out what they were used for. Thank you guys. I'll check out some of the Facebook groups.

Comment: Go to your county registrar's office and look for old tax maps and deed books.  It's a fascinating hobby.  Some counties put some things online but there is always a treasure trove of stuff in dusty old books.  You might find details of barns, silos, and other things built around your property during its history.    This detective work is definitely not Home Improvement.

Comment: This _may_ not be appropriate for [diy.se], but it's _certainly_ not too broad! It asks precisely one question: "What are these stone blocks." How much more focused could it be??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really about home improvement.

Comment: When you own a historical property, understanding the materials originally used, re-used, and as they are currently used, including ones found buried around the property, is  essential to maintaining and improving the property.  IDK how to vote against closing.  I'd like to see more questions like this.  I don't like recommending people to go to facebook!  We can guide such questions to practical use, rather than general nostalgia, and rather than chasing them away.

Answer (score 6):

They are iron ( unlikely steel at that age ) identified by the density match to iron. The reddish color that looks like granite is rust on a pitted surface. Pig iron ( high carbon and silicon ) or wrought iron ( more or less pure iron ). An unusual shape for either as far as I know. My guess is that they are raw material intended to be made into something. A real historian would be necessary for a comprehensive identification. I have never seen a shape like that except a modern ( after 1975 ) continuous caster could cast 5 X 4.5 inch square strand.

Comment: See if your town or county has an official or self-appointed historian, who will probably know if there was an iron works on your site, or will know what local resources are available for research.   A place to start is your local library, where any books or pamphlets written by said historian would be kept.

Comment: Up through the 18th century , iron would have been relatively expensive so any use for ballast would be very unlikely.  Maybe raw material for a foundry to make cannons ?

Comment: I get 8.2 g/cm³ which agrees with the published value for iron of 7.9 g/cm³. How many are there? Wonder what the value is? Is it magnetic?

Comment: From a simple engineer basis , I use 500 lb /ft cubed for the big simple picture

Comment: I started looking at the big picture long ago;  When selecting 12" diameter. cutouts from a 7" thick pressure vessel; and it was pointed out  that I had asked for over 1000 lb of samples to get 5 lb of test coupons.